# Why null data is returned is it saving or not in internal storage because not working in without sd card phone

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, uri

Why return null data return is it save or not in internal storage because not working in without sd card phone when I am returning after capture then crash app in redmii phone and this is logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null}

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
at com.logiclump.technologies.gigmedico.Home.onActivityResult(Home.java:130)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6562)
```

**This is first activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);


 private static File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FotoAula");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            file.getLastPathSegment();
            file=data.getData();
            if (file !=null)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imgUrl", file.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**his is second activity where I'm seting image in imageView**

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.e("ashish", bundle.getString("imgUrl") + "");
         path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));

    }

    ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
    selfiiii.setImageURI(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change onActvityResult Code .

```
 Instead

    file.getLastPathSegment();
                file=data.getData();
                if (file !=null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imgUrl", file.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
    **try this**
     File file = getOutputMediaFile();
     String path = getPath(Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imgUrl", path );
                    startActivity(intent);
```

**second activity**

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

uriPath = bundle.getString("imgUrl");

**getPath method**

**

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        // deal with different Uris.
        if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }**



/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: u did not define isExternalStorageDocument,isDownloadsDocument and isMediaDocument

Comment: what is these three mathod

Comment: sir coming this in logcat

Comment: E/ashish: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/FotoAula/IMG_20180329_175730.jpg
03-29 17:57:31.247 15612-15612/com.logiclump.technologies.gigmedico E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/FotoAula/IMG_20180329_175730.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)